# Как записать значение переменной в базу данных Unity?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, unity3d

Как записать значение переменной счетчика в базу данных sqlite в unity?
фрагмент кода:

```
if (hit.transform.CompareTag("PickUp")) {
    device++;
    Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject);
    if (Application.Quit ()) {
        Application.dataPath + "/stydent.db3";
    }
}
```

Имеется переменная `devise`, которая каждый раз увеличивается при выполнении какого-то события. Нужно записать конечный результат этой переменной при выходе из программы.

Comment: не знаешь как записать в бд или как записать при выходе?

Comment: @codename0082016 запись в бд

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы поймать событие выхода из приложения используйте
`OnApplicationQuit` вызывает автоматически во всех `Monobehaviour`  скриптах, но его нужно объявить

```
void OnApplicationQuit(){}
```

Дальше `Application.dataPath + "/stydent.db3";`
Это вообще получаете просто string. Если вам надо сохранить в sql базу, вам либо надо писать свой плагин, который в фоновом режиме будет производить запись каких-то параметров, и получать их из вызовов в Unity через `CallStatic` (либо найти готовый). 
В этом плане погуглите, ну или вот есть небольшая статья по этой теме [туц](https://habrahabr.ru/post/181239/)

p.s. Но имейте ввиду, что `OnApplicationQuit` вызывается только, вы вызываете `Application.Quit()`, то есть допустим пользователь нажал кнопку выйти из игры, вы должны вызвать эту функцию. И также пользователь может ее завершить не корректно, через диспетчер, или она "вылетит", и `OnApplicationQuit` не сработает.

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете плагин для sqlite? Если да, то там всё довольно просто:

При подключении базы вы создаёте подключение к ней и хешируете его:

```
private SQLiteConnection _connection;
_connection = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath, SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite);
```

dbPath - путь до базы, включающий и её название. Вторым параметром тип соединения.
В базе у тебя есть так называемые Table - таблицы с определёнными столбцами.
Создай в unity класс с такими же параметрами, как и в нужной таблице. Например, если тебе нужен только параметр и его значение:

```
using SQLite4Unity3d;

public class PARAMS {

    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, NotNull]
    public string PARAM { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    public int VALUE{ get; set; }

    public override string ToString() {
        return string.Format (
            "[mess: Param= {0}, " +
            "value: {1}.]", 
            PARAM , VALUE
        );
    }
}
```

Для добавления в ДБ делается вызов следующего вида:

```
    public void InsertParam(string param, int value)
    {
        var p = new PARAMS 
        {
            PARAM = param,
            VALUE = value
        };
        _connection.Insert(p);
    }
```

Соответственно, как сказали чуть выше, если приложение закроется экстренно, то void OnApplicationQuit(){} не отработает. Поэтому лучше всего сохранять значение сразу после его изменения.